# CPU load of the running process

Tags: windows, cpu

I need to **programmatically** know (c/c++) what is the instant CPU load of the current running process.
Win32 API offers a lot of low level API but I am unable to find one that gives me the current CPU load of my running c/c++ program.

**The question is**: how to programmatically know how many percents of CPU load the current process is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use performance counters progrmatically. See [Using Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373209(VS.85).aspx) and [some example code](http://en.literateprograms.org/CPU_usage_using_performance_counters_(C,_Windows_XP)).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use perfmon to get the CPU use of any process by id - just look up the use for your process id.